# Objects in Database only partly stored

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Person, a PersonManager, a PersonManagerABC and Child class.

The PersonManager has a field with a List of Persons (OneToMany).

It's PersonManagerABC has a field of type Child.

The List is properly stored in the DB and can be accessed from it.
But the Child disappeared after storing it in the DB (test gives null)

I guess it is only a minor thing but I cannot find it. I use Spring Boot, Hibernate 5, CrudRepositry and H2 file DB. Please help me.

**Child**

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    final String localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;
    @OneToOne
    private PersonManagerAbc personManagerAbc;

    public String getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public PersonManagerAbc getPersonManagerAbc() {
        return personManagerAbc;
    }

    public void setPersonManagerAbc(PersonManagerAbc personManagerAbc) {
        this.personManagerAbc = personManagerAbc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Child son = (Child) o;

        if (localDateTime != null ? !localDateTime.equals(son.localDateTime) : son.localDateTime != null) return false;
        return ID.equals(son.ID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = localDateTime != null ? localDateTime.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + ID.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("Child: " + localDateTime);
        return localDateTime;
    }
}
```

**PersonManager**

```
@Entity
public class PersonManager extends PersonManagerAbc {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personManager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Person> personList = new LinkedList<>();
    private String time = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long personManager_id;

    public PersonManager(String name, Child child) {
        super(name, child);
    }

    public PersonManager() {

    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        personList.add(person);
        person.setPersonManager(this);
    }

    public void deletePerson(Person person) {
        personList.remove(person);
        person.setPersonManager(this);
    }

    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
    }

    public Long getPersonManager_id() {
        return personManager_id;
    }

    public void setPersonManager_id(Long personManager_id) {
        this.personManager_id = personManager_id;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonManager{" +
                "localDateTime='" + getTime() + '\'' +
                ", time='" + time + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**PersonManagerAbc**

```
public abstract class PersonManagerAbc {

    private String localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child child;
    private String name;

    public PersonManagerAbc(String name, Child child) {
        this.child = child;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PersonManagerAbc() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    public void setLocalDateTime(String localDateTime) {
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PersonManagerAbc that = (PersonManagerAbc) o;

        return child != null ? child.equals(that.child) : that.child == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return child != null ? child.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

**HibernateApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateApplication {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addCustomers(PersonManagerRepo personManagerRepo) {
        return (args) -> {
            if (personManagerRepo.count() < 1) {
                PersonManager personManager = new PersonManager("PersonManager", new Child());
                personManager.addPerson(new Person("Hans", personManager));
                personManager.addPerson(new Person("Peter", personManager));
                personManager.addPerson(new Person("Max", personManager));
                personManagerRepo.save(personManager);
            }

            for (PersonManager personManager1 : personManagerRepo.findAll()) {
                log.info("personManager1.getPersonList().size() " + personManager1.getPersonList().size());
                log.info("personManager1.toString()" + personManager1.toString());
                log.info("personManager1.toString()" + personManager1.getChild());
            }
            log.info("");

        };
    }


    /**
     * Start internal H2 server so we can query the DB from IDE
     *
     * @return H2 Server instance
     * @throws SQLException
     */
     /*
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
    */
}
```

**Log**

```
2017-06-13 20:10:59.097  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-13 20:10:59.123  INFO 5864 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4516af24: startup date [Tue Jun 13 20:10:59 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-13 20:10:59.868  INFO 5864 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d3c1eef] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-13 20:11:00.082  INFO 5864 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-13 20:11:00.089  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-13 20:11:00.090  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-13 20:11:00.146  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-13 20:11:00.146  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1025 ms
2017-06-13 20:11:00.220  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.222  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.222  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.222  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.222  INFO 5864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.436  INFO 5864 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-13 20:11:00.442  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-06-13 20:11:00.474  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-13 20:11:00.475  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-13 20:11:00.475  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-13 20:11:00.496  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-13 20:11:00.548  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-06-13 20:11:00.835  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table person if exists
Hibernate: drop table person_manager if exists
Hibernate: create table person (person_id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), person_manager_person_manager_id bigint, primary key (person_id))
Hibernate: create table person_manager (person_manager_id bigint generated by default as identity, time varchar(255), primary key (person_manager_id))
Hibernate: alter table person add constraint FK1f8x3d159vm6o4vc2yvuebj01 foreign key (person_manager_person_manager_id) references person_manager
2017-06-13 20:11:00.847  INFO 5864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-06-13 20:11:00.862  INFO 5864 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-13 20:11:01.110  INFO 5864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4516af24: startup date [Tue Jun 13 20:10:59 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-13 20:11:01.153  INFO 5864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-06-13 20:11:01.153  INFO 5864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-06-13 20:11:01.169  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-13 20:11:01.169  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-13 20:11:01.187  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-13 20:11:01.318  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-13 20:11:01.346  INFO 5864 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-13 20:11:01.365  INFO 5864 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from person_manager personmana0_
Hibernate: insert into person_manager (person_manager_id, time) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person (person_id, name, person_manager_person_manager_id) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person (person_id, name, person_manager_person_manager_id) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person (person_id, name, person_manager_person_manager_id) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select personmana0_.person_manager_id as person_m1_1_, personmana0_.time as time2_1_ from person_manager personmana0_
Hibernate: select personlist0_.person_manager_person_manager_id as person_m3_0_0_, personlist0_.person_id as person_i1_0_0_, personlist0_.person_id as person_i1_0_1_, personlist0_.name as name2_0_1_, personlist0_.person_manager_person_manager_id as person_m3_0_1_ from person personlist0_ where personlist0_.person_manager_person_manager_id=?
2017-06-13 20:11:01.450  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : personManager1.getPersonList().size() 3
2017-06-13 20:11:01.450  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : personManager1.toString() PersonManager{localDateTime='2017-06-13T20:11:01.411', time='2017-06-13T20:11:01.411'}
2017-06-13 20:11:01.450  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : personManager1.getChild() null
2017-06-13 20:11:01.450  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : 
2017-06-13 20:11:01.451  INFO 5864 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : Started HibernateApplication in 2.499 seconds (JVM running for 2.73)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove in Child

> @OneToOne
>       private PersonManagerAbc personManagerAbc;

and the setter/getter